# Open GL :- Filling portion of quadrilateral with color

Tags: opengl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Open GL :- Filling portion of quadrilateral](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652787/open-gl-filling-portion-of-quadrilateral)

I am new to open Gl development and developing a game in which I want to show energy level of player. For which I want to fill a portion of quadrilateral.

Plz help me in creating q quadrilateral whose some portion is filled?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've made a few simple health bars in OpenGL. The first one is what you asked for, the others were for fun :)

All code is in old OpenGL for sake of exposition. The functions take health as a number between 0 and 1 and draw a square of height 1.0 at y = 0, centered on the Y axis. The screenshots show health at 0.3, 0.5 and 1.0.

1. Rectangle's height is proportional to health:

   ```
   void drawHealth(float health) {
     glBegin(GL_QUADS);
       glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
       glVertex2f(0, 0);
       glVertex2f(1, 0);
       glVertex2f(1, health);
       glVertex2f(0, health);
     glEnd();
   }
   ```

   [image: drawHealth]
2. Rectangle's colour is proportional to health:

   ```
   void drawHealth2(float health) {
     glBegin(GL_QUADS);
       glColor3f(health, 0, 0);
       glVertex2f(0, 0);
       glVertex2f(1, 0);
       glVertex2f(1, 1);
       glVertex2f(0, 1);
     glEnd();
   }
   ```

   [image: drawHealth2]
3. This version creates a sort of gradient. It looks nice when animated, the picture doesn't quite do it justice.

   ```
   void drawHealth3(float health) {
     glBegin(GL_QUADS);
       glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
       glVertex2f(0, 0);
       glVertex2f(1, 0);
       glColor3f(health, 0, 0);
       glVertex2f(1, health);
       glVertex2f(0, health);
       glVertex2f(0, health);
       glVertex2f(1, health);
       glColor3f(0, 0, 0);
       glVertex2f(1, 1);
       glVertex2f(0, 1);
     glEnd();
   }
   ```

   [image: drawHealth3]
4. This version draws discrete bars.

   ```
   void drawHealth4(float health) {
     const int numDiv = 15;
     const float sep = 0.04;
     const float barHeight = 1.0/(float)numDiv;
     glBegin(GL_QUADS);
       glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
       for(float i = 0; i < health; i += (sep + barHeight)) {
         glVertex2f(0, i);
         glVertex2f(1, i);
         glVertex2f(1, i + barHeight);
         glVertex2f(0, i + barHeight);
       }
     glEnd();
   }
   ```

   [image: drawHealth4]

Comment: Thank you descriptive suggestion. I liked concept of discrete bars. I implemented the same with some modifications :).

Answer (score 2):

```
glColor4f(r,g,b,a);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glVertex2d(-R,-1.0);
glVertex2d(R,-1.0);
glVertex2d(R,1.0);
glVertex2d(-R,1.0);
glEnd();
```

Here is an example to draw a quad of what color you want, jsut replace the parameters of glVertex2d with the endpoints of your quad. To make a energy level bar simply draw one background quad, then draw a quad inside it to represent the filled portion.  Use the coordinates to control the size of the inside quad.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two quadrilateral instead of one of dynamic length .

1. First initialize two quadrilateral (say A and B)of length x and l-x .
2. id strength increases, you only have to increase the length of A and decrease the length of B by same amount.

I think this is sufficient to get the idea.